# Regex C++ различия в синтаксисе

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++11

Данный код написанный на с++ по идеи должен возвращать мне каждое выражение внутри [], проверенно на сайте https://regex101.com/, однако вместо возвращения [1,2,3] [4,5,6]... он возвращает только первый массив и тройку. Хотелось бы знать что я делаю не так.

```
string line = " [[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]";
regex expr("\\[(\\d+,?)+\\]");

smatch m;

regex_search(line, m, expr);

for (auto x : m)
    cout << x << " ";
```

Comment: `regex_search` возвращает только первое вхождение. Используйте `std::sregex_iterator`.